# Attach strings in filename

Tags: string, fortran, filenames, fortran77

Now I have something like this

```
program prova
CHARACTER (LEN=4) :: mvalue
common mvalue   
mvalue='01.0'
call funzione(var1, var2,...)
end

subroutine funzione()
common mvalue
*(stuff with var1, var2, ...)*
open(10,file="./prova_"//mvalue//"_.res")
end
```

and the compiler returns

```
 open(10,file="./prova_"//mvalue//"_.res")                         
                                        1
 Error: Operands of string concatenation operator at (1) are CHARACTER(1)/INTEGER(4)
```

---

I don't know if I can use the "implicit none" instruction in the real code, because maybe it would mess up something else...I'm sorry if I can't be more precise, but as I told you I'm new to FORTRAN, and the code is kinda extended (and written EXTREMELY poorly).
I'd prefer to pass the mvalue variable to the routine, but if I try to do

```
program prova
CHARACTER (LEN=4) :: mvalue
mvalue="01.0"
call func(mvalue)
end


subroutine func(mvalue)
open(10,file="./prova_"//mvalue//"_.res")
end
```

it returns

```
open(10,file="./prova_"//mvalue//"_.res")                         
                           1
Error: Operands of string concatenation operator at (1) are CHARACTER(1)/INTEGER(4)

prova.f:4.16:
call func(mvalue)                                                 
Warning: Type mismatch in argument 'mvalue' at (1); passed CHARACTER(1) to INTEGER(4)
```

Comment: `"_R00.res'` Does not look right, you must use the same `"` or `'`.

Comment: `'unknown"` is invalid as well.

Comment: Another recommendation: I don't see any reason for ever using `status='unknown'`. Just leave it out. Or use some known status value if you have a reason to.

Comment: You must show a complete code sample. See *How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example* http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's a 7000 lines long code, I only showed this part because I think the error is here, since it worked perfectly fine before my modification (the filenames used to be fixed)...do you need to know anything else in particular?

Comment: Have you even looked at my link? It shows you **How to create a Minimal,..Example** from your large code.

Comment: You should not completely change your question so much. The first one was just a typo, OK, but then it is probably time for a new question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this way I could keep the people who were answering involved in the discussion...if I made a new question, they wouldn't get any notification, right?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Different problem -> new question. You can announce the new question in a comment to the old one. But this one is still the same problem in the end. Let it stay here.

Answer (score 2):

Your subroutine:

```
subroutine funzione()
common mvalue
*(stuff with var1, var2, ...)*
open(10,file="./prova_"//mvalue//"_.res")
end
```

is missing `implicit none` ! Always use it in every scoping unit without any exception!

The type of `mvalue` is not declared and it is therefore integer implicitly.

You must declare the type in every scoping unit. Sharing it using the `common` is not enough!

In Fortran 90 the proper thing is to use modules and not common blocks. In any programming language in general the proper way is not to share global variables (no matter if using common, using modules or any other way), but to pass the string as an argument to the subroutine.

---

To your new edit the same advice is still valid: **Your subroutine is missing `implicit none` ! Always use it in every scoping unit without any exception!**

If you can't use `implicit none` then you **MUST!!!!!** be prepared to diagnose errors coming from undeclared variables.  It is **absolutely necessary!**

A character dummy argument is declared as `character*(*) mvalue`

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters have already pointed out, you are using two different quotation markers in such a way that it passes the compile time, but fails at runtime.

The `file=` dummy argument expects a string, and it gets a very long one: The entirety of `./results/file_01.0_R00.res',status='unknown`. But when it tries to open that file, it fails: This is simply no valid file name.

Simply replacing the `'` with `"` in both instances (after `.res` and before `unknown`) should make the error go away.